# Read the SQLite format 3 DB file saved as blob in a oracle DB

Tags: sql, sqlite, oracle-sqldeveloper, sqlitestudio

I am using SQLite as a storage extension for offline functionality in my app. I have a feature where I save the entire db file in users device to my main oracle database (mainly for troubleshooting).This is of type BLOB. How can I download this file and read with SQLite studio to see the content in db?

Comment: Extract the blob from the Oracle DB. Save it to a file. Open the file with sqlite.